# add to array with javascript in struts

Tags: javascript, arrays, struts

OK I have this in a jsp page

```
<div id="productList">  
  <logic:iterate id="product" indexId="aid" name="TeamMaintenanceForm" property="team.productList">                             
          <div id='<bean:write name="product" property="id" />' >
                <bean:write name="product" property="name" /> 
          </div>        
        </logic:iterate>                                
</div>
```

Now I would like to add an object to this array with javascript something like

```
  function addProduct(){
       var object;
       object.name='newProduct';
       object.id=5;
       productList.add(newProduct);
}
```

SO that the new object shows up with the others in the array and so that when i do submit this page it gets submited to the form with the objects in the array.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  function addProduct(){
    var object;
    object.name='newProduct';
    object.id=5;

    // get the reference of div (productList)
    var productList = document.getElementById('productList')  ;

    // create the div structure of children
    var newProductDiv = "<div id='"+object.id +"' />'"+object.name + "</div>"; 

    // append the children to the productList div.
    productList.appendChild(newProductDiv);
 }
```

you can  make it parameterized

```
function addProduct(object){

    // get the reference of div (productList)
    var productList = document.getElementById('productList')  ;

    // create the div structure of children
    var newProductDiv = "<div id='"+object.id +"' />'"+object.name + "</div>"; 

    // append the children to the productList div.
    productList.appendChild(newProductDiv);
}
```